# Keyword-auto and Templates

Tags: c++

I was wondering when I should use `auto` over a `template` and vice versa. I ran some small tests and they had given the same results.
Are there pros to using `templates` over `auto`?
Does it help memory or the processor?
Is it better practice using `templates` for functions and classes and `auto` for variables?

Edit: The testing I did before asking this question was that I created two functions. There purpose was to get the greater argument given. One used a template

```
template<class T>
T bigger( T a, T b ){
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
};
```

The other I did the exact same thing except it started with

```
auto Bigger(auto a, auto b).
```

I put in the exact same variables `( int a = 25, int b = 30, float y = 26 , float z = 105, std::string me = “Bradley”), std::string food = “Pizza”` and I got the exact same results for both functions.
I am on Linux if that makes much difference. 
I hope this clarifies my question.

( I rewrote the code on the fly so if there are errors or what-not the reason is because of that. Everything compiles correctly on my end.)

Thank you for any help given.

Comment: They serve different purposes.  Can you update your question with the examples you tried?  That'd help provide clarity.

Comment: These aren't interchangeable in almost (?) any context.

Comment: While `template` and `auto` serve similar purposes (telling the compiler to determine things from the context), there is no place where they can be exchanged with each other. So, your first question already can't be answered, since it assumes a choice, and the others are as well based on a flawed assumption.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question. Where can you use either and don't understand their difference?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there pros to using templates over auto?

Not a good question as it tries to compare "apples and oranges". Start by paying attention to the fact that [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) cannot be used to refer to the *specific* typename. **It is not *named***. So for one it cannot be used to omit the actual types of function arguments. Moreover, by definition, no [*specialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) code (a big thing that is possible using templates) can be written using it.

> Does it help memory or the processor?

That is more dependent on the compiler implementation that anything else.

> Is it better practice using templates for functions and classes
>   and auto for variables?

Best practice is to make the right choice for every scenario, depending on the relevant aspects, beginning with what are you looking to accomplish? As again, these are two different tools.

Answer (score 0):

In addition that `auto` and `template` cannot be used in same context,

Difference between

```
auto Bigger = [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs; }

template <typename T>
T bigger(T lhs, T rhs)
```

is that in the former, `lhs` and `rhs` might have different types.
It is mostly equivalent to:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto Bigger(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) { return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs; }
```

So call as `bigger(4.2f, 42)` fails as cannot deduce `T` (might be `float` or `int`)
whereas `Bigger(4.2f, 42)` is fine.